# Multiple service starting with make inside docker-compose

Tags: makefile, docker, docker-compose

I have a rather simple architecture.

A frontend listen from the internet; it puts message on a message broker; the message are consume by a backend.

I have a docker-compose file for the frontend and the message broker, one for the message broker and the backend both of which works very well. However I need a complete docker-compose with all 3 of those services together.

The main problem is that either the frontend and the backend need to start using make.

As an example the frontend:

```
frontend:
  build: .
  command: make serve
  depends_on:
    - message_broker

message_broker:
  image: message/broker
```

the backend is pretty much the same.

Now I tried to just clue the two together:

```
frontend:
  build: frontend
  command: make serve
  depends_on:
    - message_broker

backend:
  build: backend
  command: make serve
  depends_on:
    - message_broker
    - frontend

message_broker:
  image: message/broker
```

However when I try to run it with `docker-compose up` I get `make: *** No rule to make target 'serve'.  Stop.` for either services, frontend and backend.

Of course there is the rule for `serve` inside each Makefile.

A single dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM golang:1.6.2

ENV PROJECT_PATH=/go/src/github.com/brocaar/lora-semtech-bridge
ENV PATH=$PATH:$PROJECT_PATH/build

# install tools
RUN go get github.com/golang/lint/golint
RUN go get github.com/kisielk/errcheck

# setup work directory
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_PATH
WORKDIR $PROJECT_PATH

# copy source code
COPY . $PROJECT_PATH

# build
RUN make build

CMD ["semtech-bridge"]
```

I have like the impression that I am running make inside the wrong directory, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your impression is correct. :p Set the [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Inside each Dockerfile, or inside the docker-compose ? Because inside each Dockerfile is already set, while I can't find much reference for setting  WORKDIR inside compose...

Comment: To further elaborate on Erik's answer, take a look at the Dockerfile's for the frontend & backend and check what directory your application is being added/copied to.  Then either adjust the Command/Entrypoint in the Dockerfile or in docker-compose to be relative to your application location.

Comment: When in doubt run the image interactive, i.e. `docker-compose run --rm frontend pwd` and double check the path.

Comment: I kinda get what is going on and it looks a little complex.

Comment: The Dockerfiles are inside a dir where I have put the docker-compose. The Dockerfiles copy all the dir inside their local path and then when I try to run `make serve` even if now the file is correct and they find the instruction the whole directory is messed up and it doesn't work...

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of a Dockerfile, hard to give any further advice as we have to guess.